# Python subprocess prints truncated output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have written a Python script which will execute a shell command and print the output to stdout.

The shell command itself connects to a backend service and prints the output (line by line)

**Issue**: Only the first line of the output is printed by the script. The expected output is a multi line output as shown below:

```
//+This is line one of output (/something/something)
This is line 2 of output…
This is line 3 of output
…
…
…
 Completed in 946 miliseconds
```

I have tried using the following ways to get the output of the command:

**Method 1**:

```
import os
import sys

something = sys.argv[1]

command = "here is the command part 1" + something + "command part 2"

os.system(command)
```

Output of the command (only the first line is printed):

```
//+This is line one of output (/something/something)
```

**Method 2**:

```
import sys
import subprocess

something = sys.argv[1]
command = "here is the command part 1" + something + "command part 2"

print subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Output of the command:

```
//+This is line one of output (/something/something)
```

**Method 3**:

```
import sys
import subprocess

something = sys.argv[1]

command = "here is the command part 1" + something + "command part 2"

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(output, err) = p.communicate()

print output
```

How can I print the complete output?

**Update**: Per the suggestions in the comments below, I redirected the output of the command to a file from within the Python script as shown below:

```
import os
import sys

something = sys.argv[1]
ofile = sys.argv[2]

command = "here is the command part 1" + something + "command part 2 >> " + ofile

os.system(command)

f = open(ofile, "r")
data = f.read()
f.close()

print data
```

It still prints only the first line of the output.

However, if I redirect the output of the command from the command line to an output file, the complete output is captured.

Thanks.

Comment: you could start by trying with another command, just to see if the command itself has a problem. Also redirect the command stdout/stderr to files outside python to see what those streams actually output

Comment: Okay,I can try that. If I run the command directly on the shell, it prints the complete output. Only from within the Python Script, I see the issue. I will write the output to a file and try. How do I redirect the command stdout/stderr to a file outside Python? The output of all the above commands can be stored in a variable and then I write the variable output to a file? Wouldn't it be the same result as printing the value of that variable to stdout?

Comment: is your shell a windows/bash/linux shell? is your command a cygwin command? And you really should try _not_ to use `shell=True` because it appears to make things easier at first, but in the end you have more issues...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The shell is bash and the OS is FreeBSD. I am not sure if it would be important but I am connected to the server over SSH. I SSH into the server and run the script from there. The version of Python is: 2.7.3

Comment: Sometimes your main process deploys a child process thus you can't capture all the output. I suggest you capture the output into a file and then read the file back. I can post an answer for this but I'm not sure if it is the case.